# Having trouble using an array field in a class populated by another class

Tags: java, class, instantiation

I am trying to output information from an array field i declared in a course class that i must use my student class to populate. Having trouble figuring out how to do that. here is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //creates a new instance of class student and course
        Student newStudent = new Student("Katie", 1234, 1, 4.0);
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>(25);
        studentList.add(newStudent);
        Course firstCourse = new Course("Java", 455, studentList);

        //get is how we retrieve and display the value
        System.out.println("Name: " + newStudent.getName() + "\nStudent ID #: " + newStudent.getStudentId()
        + "\nCredits: " + newStudent.getNumberOfCredits() + "\nGPA: " + newStudent.getGpa());

        System.out.println("Course name: " + firstCourse.getCourseName() + "\nCourse Id: "
        + firstCourse.getCourseID() + "\nStudents enrolled in course: " + firstCourse.getStudentsInCourse());
```

and my course class without the setters and getters

```
public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private int courseID;
    private ArrayList<Student> studentsInCourse = new ArrayList<Student>(25);

    public Course(String courseName, int courseID, ArrayList<Student> studentsInCourse){
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseID = courseID;
        this.studentsInCourse = studentsInCourse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to override `toString()` method inside Student class, so when printing array you will end up calling `toString()` method from Object.class instead of Student. You must somehow let Java know how to print your object details.

Here is an example (you can write it by yourself or generate it via IDE):

```
public class Student {
..
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", studentId=" + studentId +
            ", getNumberOfCredits=" + getNumberOfCredits +
            ", getGpa=" + getGpa +
            '}';
    }
}
```

**This:**
Students enrolled in course: [org.test.Student@5f78de22]

**Will change to that**
Students enrolled in course: [Student{name='Katie', studentId=1234, getNumberOfCredits=1, getGpa=4.0}]